# Where to find the module name of device in azure IoT central

Tags: azure-iot-central

GET https://{subdomain}.{centralDnsSuffixInPath}/api/preview/devices/{device_id}/modules/{module_name}/components/{component_name}/telemetry/{telemetry_name}

in this api where can i find a module name in azure iot central

Answer (score 0):

to get the list of device modules:

```
 GET https://{subdomain}.centralDnsSuffixInPath}/api/preview/devices/{device_id}/modules
```

Comment: {
    "value": []
} but it shows empty values in response

Comment: Does your device has a module? How did you provision this module?

Comment: can you please tell me where i can find or add device modules on azure IoT central